# Find angles of triangle by using {x,y} coordinates, not by the law of cosines

Tags: python, coordinates, trigonometry

I am solving this task:

> You are given the lengths for each side on a triangle. You need to
> find all three angles for this triangle. If the given side lengths
> cannot form a triangle (or form a degenerated triangle), then you must
> return all angles as 0 (zero).

I already have solved it by using the **law of cosines** and now I am trying a different approach.

**The idea is following:** rotate two sides by one degree at a time, regarding to both ends of the third side and store coordinates and current angle to separate lists. The third side is used as an offset on **X** axis for the second side. Then checking is follow: are both lists have the same coordinate? If yes - the triangle construction from these sides is possible.

**Animation of rotation:**

- rotation happens by 10 degrees at a time for demonstration
- the **E** is the path's intersection point, if no intersection, then no triangle is possible.

[image]

**The resulting triangle:**

[image]

I have written the Python solution, but it doesn't work properly. The problem is: the coordinates of both sides doesn't match well, the approximation is needed. 
**For example:** rotate side **b** to 90°, coords are (0.0, 4.0), rotate side **c** to 127°, coords are (-0.009, 3.993), so I need to compare these coordinates using approximation. In this case the `0.01` is enough. But another case can require `0.1` or more, like `a = 11, b = 20, c = 30`. I tried to tailor approximation value relative to the side sizes, but without luck.

#### The question:

How can I calculate more accurate coordinates and why my solution doesn't work as expected?

---

**Python solution:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from typing import List
from math import sin, cos, radians

def checkio(a: int, b: int, c: int) -> List[int]:

    def coords(side, side_offset):
        coord_list = []

        for degree in range(0,181):
            x = cos(radians(degree)) * side + side_offset
            y = sin(radians(degree)) * side

            coord_list.append((degree, x, y))

        return coord_list
    # make two lists with coordinates and degree, by rotating side "b" and side "c"
    b_coord_list = coords(b, 0) 
    # the side "a" is used just as an offset
    c_coord_list = coords(c, a) 

    for b_deg, b_x, b_y in b_coord_list:
        for c_deg, c_x, c_y in c_coord_list:

            # Approximate comparing
            if abs(b_x - c_x) <= 0.01 and abs(b_y - c_y) <= 0.01:
                l_angles = [b_deg, c_deg - b_deg, 180 - c_deg]
                l_angles.sort()

                # if all sides have angle, in other words if the triangle is possible
                if all(l_angles):
                    return sorted(l_angles)
        
    return [0, 0, 0]

### For testing:
#Good triangles
print(checkio(4, 4, 4))
print(checkio(3, 4, 5))
print(checkio(5, 4, 3))
print(checkio(11,20,30))
#Bad triangle
print(checkio(10, 20, 30))
```

Comment: `calculate more accurate coordinates` are you referring to `he (inner) function `coords()`? What do you mean by `more accurate`?

Comment: For the statement `if abs(b_x - c_x) <= 0.01 and abs(b_y - c_y) <= 0.01:`: are you saying you need the comparison value (`0.01`) to by dynamic and depending on the functions `b` and `c` arguments/parameters?

Comment: @wwii I know, that sides `a = 3, b = 4, c = 5` forms the triangle. Therefore, all sides should have the accurate intersection coordinates - vertexes. But my `coords` function doesn't return perfect coords, which can be comparing without tailored approximation. It returns so approximate coordinates, that I can't get precise angle of sides intersection with 1 degree accuracy.

Comment: You are calculating coordinates at one degree resolution, Do you think it would work with coordinate calculated at 1/100 degree resolution? or even finer?

Comment: @wwii It is exact problem - originally, I just wanted to compare two {x,y} coords and pick relative angles for solving the task (after rounding, of course). But it turned out, that I can't use returned coordinates directly - they will not match, so I start use approximation. Then, it turned out, that different side sizes, requires different approximation value, so my code gives very non-stable results.

Comment: @wwii 1/100 degree resolution? May be... I didn't think about it. Thanks. I will try it. But it will be much less efficient solution.

Comment: With that nested for loop, you might want to try a resolution of 0.1 degrees. Seem like a solution that provides correct results but takes more time is more efficient than a solution that is fast but incorrect.